# how to insert media files in cassandra using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, cassandra

How we insert an image into a Cassandra database using node js
I have tried with following.

I have used base64(image) to store the image, but I need store base64 in blob datatype of Cassandra. I know the blob datatype in Cassandra is equivalent to Buffer datatype in node js.

```
var cassandra=require('cassandra-driver');
var client=new cassandra.Client({contactPoints:['localhost'],localDataCenter:"datacenter1",keyspace:"employee"});
var path=require('path');
var fs=require('fs');
var base64 = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname + '/download.jpeg'), 'base64');

var imageBuffer = new Buffer(base64, 'base64');





var query="INSERT INTO photo(id,image) VALUES ('ranjith',imageBuffer)";

client.execute(query,function(err){
   if(err) {
      console.log(err);
   } else {
      console.log('success');
   }
});
```

Here is the error message:

```
> { ResponseError: line 1:57 no viable alternative at input ')'
> (...id,image) VALUES ('ranjith',[imageBuffer]))
>     at FrameReader.readError (/home/innvoot/Desktop/cassandra_and_node_trails/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/readers.js:326:15)
>     at Parser.parseBody (/home/innvoot/Desktop/cassandra_and_node_trails/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/streams.js:194:66)
>     at Parser._transform (/home/innvoot/Desktop/cassandra_and_node_trails/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/streams.js:137:10)
>     at Parser.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:186:10)
>     at Parser.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:174:12)
>     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:396:12)
>     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:382:5)
>     at Parser.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:290:11)
>     at Protocol.ondata (_stream_readable.js:639:20)
>     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)   name: 'ResponseError',   info: 'Represents an error message from the server',   message: 'line 1:57
> no viable alternative at input \')\' (...id,image) VALUES
> (\'ranjith\',[imageBuffer]))',   code: 8192,   coordinator:
> '127.0.0.1:9042',   query: 'INSERT INTO photo(id,image) VALUES
> (\'ranjith\',imageBuffer)' }
```

I expect to get "SUCCESS" as the result.

Comment: Please don't use Cassandra to store binary data, such as photos, or music, etc. There are some difficulties with handling blobs bigger than couple of hundreds kbs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no javascript expert, but seeing your error;

> no viable alternative at input \')\' (...id,image) VALUES (\'ranjith\',[imageBuffer]))'

I feel that the query syntax could be wrong, could try

```js
const query = 'INSERT INTO photo (id, image) VALUES (?, ?)';

client.execute(query, [ 'ranjith', imageBuffer ], { prepare: true }, function(err, result) {
  assert.ifError(err);
  console.log('Success');
});
```